# load table column into an array in datastage

Tags: datastage

I need to run a mathematical function on a table with two columns.
One column is a date and the other is a number.
I need to order the data by date, and for each date I need to take the number from the same date, the number from 1 date before, and the number from one date after.

I run the function on this 3 numbers.
I'm a linux programmer, for me it's very simple, I just put it in an array and run over it.
Hoe can I do it with datastage ? Can I load the data from a table into an array and do the same ? 
All I found in datastage is to run only line by line. I just want to know if something like can be done in datastage easily, and if you can 
direct me how to start working on it !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop in transformer stage. http://newtonapples.com/datastage-transformer-looping-1/
Use sort stage to sort you data by the date (it's very easy).
Then use transformer stage. create 2 loop variables one for the last row and one for the one before the last. Then apply your function to the three rows.
Here another looping example but it's a little bit more complex than the first link http://datastageinfoguide.blogspot.com/2013/01/looping-concept-in-datastage-85-or-87.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in PX, you will need a more complex solution that involves running some/all of the job sequentially. If I understand you correctly, you have:

Row A, Day 1

Row B, Day 2

Row C, Day 3

What you want:

A,  , 1, 2

B, 1, 2, 3

C, 2, 3,

First, you should run this job sequentially, even if using PX. There are ways to do this in PX but it's not worth the hassle.

Second you should sort all your data in ascending order. Use a transformer to find the number from the day before. You will get:

A,  , 1

B, 1, 2

C, 2, 3

Third take this data and sort it in descending order. Apply basically the same logic as before in another transformer. This will get you

C, 2, 3,

B, 1, 2, 3

A,  , 1, 2

HTH!